# Show that the arc length of sin(x) = circumference of ellipse

Tags: calculus, conic-sections, arc-length

I've been staring at this problem for a while, and I would really appreciate any insight into finding the solution. The problem in its original state is as follows:

Show that the arc length of the graph of $y = \sin x$ on the interval $[0, 2\pi]$ is equal to the circumference of the ellipse $x^2 + 2y^2 = 2$.

I have gotten far enough to see that the arc length of $sinx$ on the given interval is $4\sqrt2E\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ which, according to WolframAlpha "is the complete elliptic integral of the second kind with parameter $m=k^2$."

My question is first of all, where do I go from here? Will I have to use elliptic integrals of any kind in order to arrive at a coherent solution? And how does arc length relate to elliptic circumference?

Thank you!

Notes:
This is for an Honors Calculus 2 homework assignment.

Comment: Hint: $ \sqrt{1+\cos^2x} =  \sqrt{(\sqrt{2}\cos x)^2 + \sin^2 x}$

Comment: You don't need to evaluate the integral to show equality.

Comment: @achillehui Thank you for the hint, but I don't quite see how it relates to the circumference of the ellipses. I understand that $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ but I can't find any way to proceed from there. I tried to find an equation that would describe the ellipse but I've come up empty. Any further help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is within the scope of 'Calculus 2':

The length of a smooth curve $\gamma:[0,2 \pi] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is give by
$l(\gamma) = \int_0^{2 \pi} \|\gamma'(t)\| dt$.

The first curve is $\gamma_1(t) = (t, \sin t)$, the
second can be written as
$\gamma_2(t) = (\sqrt{2} \sin t, \cos t)$ (I choose this parameterisation, as opposed to $t \mapsto  (\sqrt{2} \cos t, \sin t)$, since the equality is
immediate).

You will find that $\|\gamma_1'(t) \| = \|\gamma_2'(t) \| $, hence the
lengths are equal.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. As I don't recognize the formulas or the parameterisation that you used, I don't think I understand this yet. Is there another way to show the equality using just calculus?

Comment: @copper.hat I have a related question. I want to find the total projected length of the sinusoid (see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3617566/finding-the-horizontal-extent-of-a-sinusoid). Could you possibly help? I think I need to find an explicit parametrisation of the curve in terms of `s`.