# Finding the horizontal extent of a sinusoid

Tags: calculus, integration, parametrization, arc-length

I need some help with a calculus problem. Suppose you have a straight line of length `L`, and you squeeze it into a sinusoid with `m` folds amplitude `A`: 
$$ \rm y(x) = A cos(m x)$$

[image: m=3 here]

Then what is the new horizontal extent $\rm L_x$, defined as 
$$ \rm L_x =\int dx = \int_0^L ds \, cos(\theta) 
$$
where $\rm s $ is the arc length, and $\rm \theta$ is the slope w.r.t the horizontal.

The question then boils down to finding a parametrisation of $\theta(s)$ in terms of $\rm s$? It would be simplest to just consider a single fold, I guess, and then extrapolate to `m` folds.

Comment: Unfortunately, the solution requires a special function (Elliptic integral).

Comment: That's fine. I need the actual number, so I can use Mathematica once I have a closed-form integral. Can you please help further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the function $a\sin\theta$ over a quarter-period,

$$S=\int ds=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{1+a^2\cos^2\theta}\,d\theta.$$

Using WA,

$$S=\sqrt{a^2+1}\,E\left(\frac{a^2}{a^2+1}\right)$$ where $E$ is the complete elliptic integral of the second kind.

So the ratio of the unfolded over the folded length is

$$\frac2\pi\sqrt{a^2+1}\,E\left(\frac{a^2}{a^2+1}\right).$$

Comment: Sorry, I am missing a step here. Are you using $\theta$ in the same sense I am, as the angle w.r.t. the horizontal? Or is just same arbitrary parameter?

Comment: @ap21: $a$ and $\theta$ are in the same unit.

Comment: And what is WA?

Comment: @ap21: Wolfram Alpha.